# Profile time taken by Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a huge number of jobs in multiple queues, and I'm wondering if it would be possible to profile the time taken by each job?

Answer (score 1):

You can grep after it from the production log if you are using bash:

```
$ awk '/COMPLETED after/ {print $NF}' production.log | sort -nr | head
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ice799/memprof.

Also to record different events of job you can use hookshttps://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/README.md#hooks